# XPath to select mixed content (text and elements) children?

Tags: xml, xpath

I need an XPath expression that allows me to select both text and XML markup from an element without including the parent element tags. Using the example below, I need to select the content of `<title>` from the context of `<fig>` without the `<title>` tags.

```
<fig>
 <title>An H<sub>2</sub>O molecule</title>
 <image href="h2oMolecule.jpg"/>
<fig>
```

In other words, I need to be able to capture this:

```
An H<sub>2</sub>O molecule
```

From `<fig>` I've tried `child::title/*`, `child::title/node()`, and `child::title/*[text() or node()]`, but all return `<sub>2</sub>`.

I also tried `child::title/text()` but I get "An H".

Is there a way to use XPath to get mixed content from an element without also taking the parent element tags?

Answer (score 0):

> from `<fig>` I've tried `child::title/*`, `child::title/node()`, and `child::title/*[text() or node()]`, but all return `<sub>2</sub>`.

No, that would not be true for `child::title/node()`.  You made some other error.  It would be true for the `*` XPaths because `*` means any element, and `<sub>2</sub>` is the only child element of `fig`.

For your XML corrected to be well-formed,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<fig>
 <title>An H<sub>2</sub>O molecule</title>
 <image href="h2oMolecule.jpg"/>
</fig>
```

this XPath,

```
/fig/title/node()
```

selects these nodes,

```
An H<sub>2</sub>O molecule
```

as requested because `node()` includes both element and text nodes.